# Tuples vs Composite Tuples vs Components in Datomic

Tags: datomic

What's the difference between ***tuples***, ***composite tuples***, and ***components***, in datomic?

I am finding this one of the most difficult to understand aspects of the schema. I find the documentation (which is on the whole excellent) not clear enough in explaining this from scratch, pehaps because of a lack of examples, and haven't yet found a talk that covers it, up to date or otherwise.

Here's what I've been able to find out (which may be wrong):

- A tuple seems a bit like an array in postgres.
- A composite tuple seems how you can add a composite key, i.e. uniqueness across more than one attribute.
- A component is how you define a document like structure, mainly so you can gain cascading deletes.

Comment: David Nolen mentions isComponent at 25:30 in "Clients in Control" here:https://docs.datomic.com/on-prem/videos.html

Answer (score 1):

Tuples in Datomic add a more flexible uniqueness constraint and allow you to precompute optimal joins, nothing more.

From the Datomic blog (release note):

> You can use tuples to create multi-attribute unique keys on domain entities. You can also use tuples to optimize queries that otherwise would have to join two or more high-population attributes.

The reason Datomic has 3 kinds of tuples is because you need homogeneous variable length tuples to define heterogeneous fixed length tuples which you then need to define composite tuples.

Composite tuples are then just convenience.

While tuples sound like something you might want, you lose some flexibility. For example, if you don't have underlying attributes to query, you can't use the VAET index (assuming there's a `:db.type/ref` in there). This is why I believe tuples are a performance feature on top and that you should stick to just composite tuples and not bother with the other kinds.

For example, you can't put tuple attributes in composite tuples if you ever needed to do that but you could have done that if all your tuples were composite tuples because it would just be a different set of attributes.

You should not consider tuples to be part of your schema. Rather, think of them as something you graft on top to facilitate certain things.

---

With regards to components, I'll give you a JSON document analogy. The attributes that reference the structure in that document are the components. Components because of how they behave should not be shared (not that you couldn't). Because when you retract an entity, it will retract all it's referenced components as well. That's why you don't share components. Back to the JSON document, any object or array in that document is thus a component of the root. And of course, components can have components. You can think of such a structure as a sensible unit of data but it's a much more complex structure.

Answer (score 0):

In regard to components, and why you might want to use them, I found David Nolen's principles in the talk "Clients in Control" helps a lot:

Desirable properties

1. Clients can request the precise total response that they need.
2. Clients can make atomic commits of data trees without sacrificing relational queries server side.

In broad terms, isComponent is a way of helping these principles to be achieved.

And from the [blog entry](https://blog.datomic.com/2013/06/component-entities.html) introducing components:

> Components allow you to create substantial trees of data with nested maps, and then treat the entire tree as a single unit for lifecycle management (particularly retraction).  All nested items remain visible as first-class targets for query, so *the shape of your data at transaction time does not dictate the shape of your queries*.  This is a key value proposition of Datomic when compared to row, column, or document stores.

To say more than this, we'd need to work through some detailed examples.